# Solve SIR model using Euler's method in C#

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method, epidemiology

The SIR model is:

$$ \begin{aligned} \dot S &= −\beta I S\\ \dot I &= \beta I S − \gamma I \\ \dot R &= \gamma I \end{aligned} $$

I know how to solve SIR with Euler's method in C#. I don't know how to create a suitable class file. Would anyone familiar with C# be able to help please!?

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Take a look at chapter 16 http://numerical.recipes/C210

Comment: What would be the capabilities of instances of this class? Would it be a stepper, or a solver producing function tables?